# Rails has_many through with where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need help to achieve something.

Is it possible that my Analysis `has_many :klasses, through: :subjects`, but filtered using attributes from the join table AnalysisSubject? Or my models should be different?

```
class Analysis
  has_many :analysis_subjects, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :subjects, through: :analysis_subjects
  has_many :klasses, -> { where(year: ??????, semester: ??????), through: :subjects
end

class AnalysisSubject
  belongs_to :analysis
  belongs_to :subject

  # There are year:integer and semester:integer attributes
  # I want to use those attributes in my where clause for analysis.klasses
end

class Subject
  has_many :klasses
  has_many :analysis_subjects
  has_many :analyses, through: :analysis_subjects
end

class Klass
  belongs_to :subject
end
```

I'm using Rails 5 if it is important. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you should afford it in a different way: You must declare the `where` in a `has_many :filtered_analysis_subjects`.

```
class Analysis
  has_many :filtered_analisys_subjects, -> { where(year: x, semester: y }, foreign_key: "analysis_id", class_name: "AnalysisSubject", dependent: :destroy 
  has_many :subjects, through: :filtered_analysis_subjects
  has_many :klasses, through: :subjects
```